# Azure function published through visual studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working on migration to Azure and developing azure functions in my local using visual studio. I have published the code from local to Azure function app. Recently, my laptop got crashed and I don't have the code in the git repo. Is there any way I could get the code from the azure portal as I have published the recent code there. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What language was the function written in?  C#, JS?

Comment: Hi Bryan - It was in C#

Comment: You can find the answer here in Stack Overflow [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398069/where-can-i-find-the-code-of-an-azure-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a C# based Function, your code is going to have been compiled into a DLL before it's sent to Azure.  So you will be able to locate the publish location using the link Rajkumar provided above.  However, the DLL will only be useful if you can successfully decompile it back to source.  The Publish process doesn't place any source on Azure.

So you could use something like JetBrain's C# decompiler (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to recover your source...but sometimes those things don't work well.  Give it a try and be sure to commit often next time!  ;)

Comment: Thanks Bryan for the response. Fortunately, the visual studio workspace was getting synced with onedrive. I actually tried the download app content option in function app but it was giving bad request in the activity log. I am not sure if download app content works in such scenarios.

Comment: It sounds like you got your source from OneDrive, but if you need to manually push/pull files from an App Service (which a Func App really is), you can always use FTP.  This allows you direct access for upload/download.  Go to the Deployment Center tab in the Function App and click on the FTPS option for the login info.